# Shell variable substitution in command

Tags: bash, scripting

How can i get the below command working.

```
export CURDATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/type" \
  -d ' { "AlertType": "IDLE", "@timestamp": $CURDATE }'
```

I am getting error "reason":"Unrecognized token '$CURDATE': was expecting"
How do i get the variable substitution correct in the code above

Comment: single quotes will block expansion of shell variables.

Comment: In the future, the "create snippet" button is for HTML and JavaScript only (they allow code to be demonstrated in the viewer's browser). Use the `{}` button in the editor for code formatting in all other languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes will not expand variables, use double quotes:

```
curdate=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/type" \
  -d '{"AlertType": "IDLE", "@timestamp": "'"$curdate"'"}'
```

I also added JSON quotes around the expansion so it becomes something like:

```
{"AlertType": "IDLE", "@timestamp": "2016-05-23"}
```

There shouldn't be any need to export the variable. And usually only environment variables are written all caps. And last I changed the command substitution to `$(...)`

```
'{"AlertType": "IDLE", "@timestamp": "'"$curdate"'"}'
#                                    ^^
#                                    |End singlequotes
#                                    JSON quote
```

Comment: Also export was not necessary here and even if it was needed export should have been done after the assignment to avoid masking of return values.

Comment: It might be worth demonstrating using `jq` to generate guaranteed-to-be-valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to hand-write your JSON, it's simpler to read it from standard input than try to embed it in an argument:

```
curl -XPOST -d@- "$URL" <<EOF
{ "AlertType": "IDLE",
  "@timestamp": "$CURDATE"
}
EOF
```

You should use a tool like `jq` to generate the JSON for you, though.

```
date +%F | jq -R '{AlertType: "IDLE", "@timestamp": .}' | curl -XPOST -d@- "$URL"
```

or letting `json` built the timestamp entirely on its own

```
jq -n '{AlertType: "IDLE", "@timestamp": (now | strftime("%F"))}' | curl ...
```